# Flutter game four in a row freeze randomly

Tags: flutter

I have a working example of a four in a row game, but randomly the game freeze. some time at the middle of the game, but always at the end if there is no winner. I spot a negative variable who appeared when it freeze but I don't know where it come from and why and how to prevent this.

Here is the complet test example who can be launch on dart pad (but just need resize view to show board)

The problem seems to be located in `void putChip(int col)`  when `target` `=` `-1` it freeze.

[image]

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(puissance());


class puissance extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: '',

      home: HomePage(),
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        final args = settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
        if (settings.name == '/match') {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => MatchPage(
              mode: args['mode'],
              cpu: args['cpu'],

            ),
          );
        } else if (settings.name == '/cpu-level') {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => CpuLevelPage(),
          );
        }

        return null;
      },
    );
  }
}




class Board {
  List<List<Player?>> _boxes = List.generate(
    7,
        (i) => List.generate(
      7,
          (i) => null,
    ),
  );

  Board();

  Board.from(List<List<Player?>> boxes) {
    _boxes = boxes;

  }

  Player? getBox(Coordinate coordinate) =>
      _boxes[coordinate.col][coordinate.row];
  int getColumnTarget(int col) => _boxes[col].lastIndexOf(null);

  void setBox(Coordinate coordinate, Player player) =>
      _boxes[coordinate.col][coordinate.row] = player;

  void reset() {
    _boxes.forEach((r) => r.forEach((p) => p = null));
  }


}

//------------------coordinate---------
class Coordinate {
  final int row, col;

  Coordinate(
      this.col,
      this.row,
      );

  Coordinate copyWith({
     int? col,
     int? row,
  }) =>
      Coordinate(
        col ?? this.col,
        row ?? this.row,
      );
}


//-----------------------cpu ---------------------------


abstract class Cpu {
  final Player player;
  final Random _random = Random(DateTime.now().millisecond);

  Cpu(this.player);

  Player get otherPlayer => player == Player.RED ? Player.YELLOW : Player.RED;

  Future<int> chooseCol(Board board);
}

class DumbCpu extends Cpu {
  DumbCpu(Player player) : super(player);

  Player get otherPlayer => player == Player.RED ? Player.YELLOW : Player.RED;

  @override
  Future<int> chooseCol(Board board) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: _random.nextInt(2)));
    int col = _random.nextInt(7);
    return col;
  }

  @override
  String toString() => 'DUMB CPU';
}



//-------------cpu level---------


class CpuLevelPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[

            new RawMaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  '/match',
                  arguments: {
                    'mode': Mode.PVC,
                    'cpu': DumbCpu(
                        Random().nextBool() ? Player.RED : Player.YELLOW),
                  },
                );
              },
              child: Text("level1",style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  fontSize: 15),
              ),
              shape: new CircleBorder(),
              elevation: 2.0,
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
            ),



          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


//--------------game_chip-----------------------


class GameChip extends StatelessWidget {
  const GameChip({
    Key? key,
     this.translation,
     this.color,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Animation<double>? translation;
  final Player? color;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
          0,
          ((translation?.value ?? 1) * 400) - 400,
          0,
        ),
        height: 40,
        width: 40,
        child: Material(
          shape: CircleBorder(),
          color: color == Player.RED ? Color(0xffff9a7b) :Color(0xfff9f396),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//-----------------hole painter---------------


class HolePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint();
    paint.color =  Color(0xff61d3cb);
    canvas.drawPath(
      Path.combine(
        PathOperation.difference,
        Path()
          ..addRRect(RRect.fromLTRBR(
            -1,
            -1,
            size.width,
            size.height,
            Radius.zero,
          )),
        Path()
          ..addOval(Rect.fromCircle(
            center: Offset(size.width / 2, size.width / 2),
            radius: 20,
          ))
          ..close(),
      ),
      paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}


//----------------home_page-----------


class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: true,

      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            new RawMaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  '/cpu-level',
                  arguments: {
                    'mode': Mode.PVC,
                  },
                );


              },
              child: Text("CPU mode", textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  fontSize:15),
              ),
              shape: new CircleBorder(),
              elevation: 2.0,
              fillColor:Colors.white,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
            ),


          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//---------------------------------match_page--------------------


enum Player {
  YELLOW,
  RED,
}

enum Mode {
  PVC,
  DEMO,
}

class MatchPage extends StatefulWidget {
   Mode? mode;
   Cpu? cpu;


   MatchPage({
    Key? key,
     this.mode,
     this.cpu,

  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MatchPageState createState() => _MatchPageState();
}

class _MatchPageState extends State<MatchPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final board = Board();
   Player turn= Player.RED ;
     Player? winner;

  List<List<Animation<double>?>> translations = List.generate(
    7,
        (i) => List.generate(
      7,
          (i) => null,
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
     turn == widget.cpu?.player ?
          IgnorePointer(child:        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(

              children: <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Positioned.fill(
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        buildPieces(),
                        buildBoard(),


                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),

          ):

        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(

            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                flex: 2,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Positioned.fill(
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      buildPieces(),
                      buildBoard(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: winner != null
                      ? Text(
                    'Les ${winner == Player.RED ? 'Rouges' : 'Jaunes'} Gagnent',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontSize: 15),

                  )
                      : ListView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Au tour des ${turn == Player.RED ? 'Rouges' : 'Jaunes'} ',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 15),

                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: GameChip(color: turn),
                      ),
                      _buildPlayerName(context),

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        ],
      )



    );
  }

   _buildPlayerName(BuildContext context) {
    String name;

    if (widget.mode == Mode.PVC) {
      if (turn == widget.cpu!.player) {
        name = 'Ordinateur';
      } else {
        name = 'Toi';
      }
    }
      if (turn == widget.cpu!.player) {
        name = 'Ordinateur';
      } else {
        name = 'Ordinateur';

    }
    return Column(
      children: [
      Text(
      name,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          fontSize:15),

    ),
     turn == widget.cpu?.player ? CircularProgressIndicator():Container()


     ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (widget.mode == Mode.PVC && turn == widget.cpu?.player) {
      cpuMove(widget.cpu!);
    } else if (widget.mode == Mode.DEMO) {
      if (turn == widget.cpu?.player) {
        cpuMove(widget.cpu!);
      }
    }
  }

  GridView buildPieces() {
    return GridView.custom(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      gridDelegate:
      SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 7),
      childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (context, i) {
          final col = i % 7;
          final row = i ~/ 7;

          if (board.getBox(Coordinate(col, row)) == null) {
            return SizedBox();
          }

          return GameChip(
            translation: translations[col][row],
            color: board.getBox(Coordinate(col, row)),
          );
        },
        childCount: 49,
      ),
    );
  }

  GridView buildBoard() {
    return GridView.custom(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      gridDelegate:
      SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 7),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (context, i) {
          final col = i % 7;

          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              if (winner == null) {

                userMove(col);
              }
            },
            child: CustomPaint(
              size: Size(50, 50),
              willChange: false,
              painter: HolePainter(),
            ),
          );
        },
        childCount: 49,
      ),
    );
  }

  void userMove(int col) {

    putChip(col);
    if (winner == null && widget.mode == Mode.PVC) {

      cpuMove(widget.cpu!);
    }
  }

  void cpuMove(Cpu cpu) async {
    int col = await cpu.chooseCol(board);

    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {

      putChip(col);


    });

  }

  void putChip(int col) {

    final target = board.getColumnTarget(col);
    print("putChip target $target ");


    if (target == -1) {

      return;
    }


    final controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
    )..addListener(() {

      if (mounted) {

        setState(() {

        });
      }
    });

    if (mounted) {

      setState(() {


        board.setBox(Coordinate(col, target), turn);
        turn = turn == Player.RED ? Player.YELLOW : Player.RED;
      });
    }

    translations[col][target] = Tween(
      begin: 0.0,
      end: 1.0,
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      curve: Curves.bounceOut,
      parent: controller,
    ))
      ..addStatusListener((status) {

        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          controller.dispose();
        }
      });

    controller.forward().orCancel;


  }

  void resetBoard() {
    setState(() {
      board.reset();
    });
  }
}
```

```
class HarderCpu extends Cpu {
  HarderCpu(Player player) : super(player);

  @override
  Future<int> chooseCol(Board board) async {
    final List<double> scores = List.filled(7, 0);

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1 + _random.nextInt(2)));
    return _compute(board, 0, 1, scores);
  }

  int _compute(Board board, int step, int deepness, List<double> scores) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
      final boardCopy = board.clone();

      var target = boardCopy.getColumnTarget(i);

      if (target == -1) {


        continue;


      }

      final coordinate = Coordinate(i, target);

      boardCopy.setBox(coordinate, player);


      if (boardCopy.checkWinner(coordinate, player)) {
        scores[i] += deepness / (step + 1);
        continue;

      }


      for (var j = 0; j < 7; ++j) {
        final target = boardCopy.getColumnTarget(j);
        if (target == -1) {
          continue;
        }

        final coordinate = Coordinate(j, target);

        boardCopy.setBox(coordinate, otherPlayer);
        if (boardCopy.checkWinner(coordinate, otherPlayer)) {
          scores[i] -= deepness / (step + 1);
          continue;
        }

        if (step + 1 < deepness) {
          _compute(board, step + 1, deepness, scores);
        }
      }
    }

    return _getBestScoreIndex(scores);
  }

  int _getBestScoreIndex(List<double> scores) {
    int bestScoreIndex = scores.indexWhere((s) => s != null);
    scores.asMap().forEach((index, score) {
      if (score != null &&
          (score > scores[bestScoreIndex] ||
              (score == scores[bestScoreIndex] && _random.nextBool()))) {
        bestScoreIndex = index;
      }
    });
    return bestScoreIndex;
  }

  @override
  String toString() => 'HARDER CPU';
}

class HardestCpu extends HarderCpu {
  HardestCpu(Player player) : super(player);

  @override
  Future<int> chooseCol(Board board) async {
    final List<double> scores = List.filled(7, 0);

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2 + _random.nextInt(2)));
    return _compute(board, 0, 4, scores);
  }

  @override
  String toString() => 'HARDEST CPU';
}
```

---

```
class Board {
  List<List<Player?>> _boxes = List.generate(
    7,
        (i) => List.generate(
      7,
          (i) => null,
    ),
  );

  Board();

  Board.from(List<List<Player?>> boxes) {
    _boxes = boxes;
  }

  Player? getBox(Coordinate coordinate) =>
      _boxes[coordinate.col][coordinate.row];

  int getColumnTarget(int col) => _boxes[col].lastIndexOf(null);

  void setBox(Coordinate coordinate, Player player) =>
      _boxes[coordinate.col][coordinate.row] = player;

  void reset() {
    _boxes.forEach((r) => r.forEach((p) => p = null));
  }

  bool checkWinner(Coordinate coordinate, Player player) {
    return checkHorizontally(coordinate, player) ||
        checkVertically(coordinate, player) ||
        checkDiagonally(coordinate, player);
  }

  bool checkHorizontally(Coordinate coordinate, Player player) {
    var r = 0;
    for (;
    coordinate.col + r < 7 &&
        r < 4 &&
        getBox(coordinate.copyWith(col: coordinate.col + r)) == player;
    ++r) {}
    if (r >= 4) {
      return true;
    }

    var l = 0;
    for (;
    coordinate.col - l >= 0 &&
        l < 4 &&
        getBox(coordinate.copyWith(col: coordinate.col - l)) == player;
    ++l) {}
    if (l >= 4 || l + r >= 5) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  bool checkDiagonally(Coordinate coordinate, Player player) {
    var ur = 0;
    for (;
    coordinate.col + ur < 7 &&
        coordinate.row + ur < 7 &&
        ur < 4 &&
        getBox(coordinate.copyWith(
          col: coordinate.col + ur,
          row: coordinate.row + ur,
        )) ==
            player;
    ++ur) {}
    if (ur >= 4) {
      return true;
    }
    var dl = 0;
    for (;
    coordinate.col - dl >= 0 &&
        coordinate.row - dl >= 0 &&
        dl < 4 &&
        getBox(coordinate.copyWith(
          col: coordinate.col - dl,
          row: coordinate.row - dl,
        )) ==
            player;
    ++dl) {}
    if (dl >= 4 || dl + ur >= 5) {
      return true;
    }

    var dr = 0;
    for (;
    coordinate.col + dr < 7 &&
        coordinate.row - dr >= 0 &&
        dr < 4 &&
        getBox(coordinate.copyWith(
          col: coordinate.col + dr,
          row: coordinate.row - dr,
        )) ==
            player;
    ++dr) {}
    if (dr >= 4) {
      return true;
    }

    var ul = 0;
    for (;
    coordinate.col - ul >= 0 &&
        coordinate.row + ul < 7 &&
        ul < 4 &&
        getBox(coordinate.copyWith(
          col: coordinate.col - ul,
          row: coordinate.row + ul,
        )) ==
            player;
    ++ul) {}
    if (ul >= 4 || dr + ul >= 5) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  bool checkVertically(Coordinate coordinate, Player player) {
    var u = 0;
    for (;
    coordinate.row + u < 7 &&
        u < 4 &&
        getBox(coordinate.copyWith(
          row: coordinate.row + u,
        )) ==
            player;
    ++u) {}
    if (u >= 4) {
      return true;
    }
    var d = 0;
    for (;
    coordinate.row - d >= 0 &&
        d < 4 &&
        getBox(coordinate.copyWith(
          row: coordinate.row - d,
        )) ==
            player;
    ++d) {}
    if (d >= 4 || d + u >= 5) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  Board clone() {
    return Board.from(_boxes.map((c) => c.map((b) => b).toList()).toList());
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide minimal snippet

Comment: I have already filter all necessary part to simulate the bug. The only thing I observed is target = -1 always when it freeze but I not really certain that is the origine of the bug

Comment: I have add more minimal snippet, in this example, there is no winner so the board can be completed until the bug appears

Comment: Can you tell the step to reproduce the error, & I was talking about [/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 

Comment: The bug can easly reproduce, all code can be copy past on dart pad with no add of package. The freeze (cpu stop to play) always before the end the full complet game. It’s quick to simulate, juste play randomly

Comment: I have add  print("putChip target $target ");  to detect the -1 who seems to be the cause of the freeze

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to play this game to get negative result

Comment: Just fill in the board randomly and between 50% - 100% of complet, the cpu stop to play and the result show -1

Comment: I edit my post with image and upgrade my code with main() =>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is just as you said in `void putChip(int col)` when `target = -1`

you get -1 here

```
int getColumnTarget(int col) => _boxes[col].lastIndexOf(null);
```

if there is no `null` value in `_boxes` for the selected `col` the index will always be -1 and of coures this will result in exucting

```
    // from putChip methoud
    if (target == -1) {
      return;
    }
```

and you would most likely get -1 because you are getting the `col` value randomly

then this line wouldn't execute

```
turn = turn == Player.RED ? Player.YELLOW : Player.RED;
```

and the game wouldn't technically freeze but when it's the cpu turn the pointer is ignored with `IgnorePointer` widget and in case you get -1 it would always be the cpu turn

You just need to deal with the case where `_boxes[col]` does not contain `null`.

Upadte : solution

one possible solution would be to check the available columns and then selecting a random one of them instead of all the columns

update `chooseCol` from `DumbCpu` class to

```
  Future<int> chooseCol(Board board) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: _random.nextInt(2)));

    // reference the available columns indexes
    final List<int> avialableClos = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < board._boxes.length; i++) {
      if (board._boxes[i].first == null) {
        avialableClos.add(i);
      }
    }
    
    // return immediately if only one column is available
    if (avialableClos.length == 1) return avialableClos.first;
    
    // return a random column from the available
    return avialableClos[_random.nextInt(avialableClos.length - 1)];
  }
```

Also, don't forget to handle the case when the user clicks on a filled column

```
  void userMove(int col) {
    // added this line
    if (board._boxes[col].first != null) return;

    putChip(col);
    if (winner == null && widget.mode == Mode.PVC) {
      cpuMove(widget.cpu!);
    }
  }
```

Another solution would be to create a separate list with the available columns and then remove from it when the user chooses and when the cpu chooses, this would have better time complexity  O(1) but it requires a lot of boilerplate and performance different wouldn't be notable I guess (in case of 7x7 matrix)

Comment: Thank you,  but I don't see how to do :(

Comment: @Nitneuq ok, I will update my answer.

Comment: I have a more difficult CPU I have upload my post. I don't know if it's possible

Comment: The post isn't updated

Comment: It's upload sorry

Comment: I have HarderCpu and HardestCpu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250024/discussion-between-mohammed-alfateh-and-nitneuq).